# React.createElement: type is invalid expected a string(for built-in components)or a class/function(for composite components)but got: %s.%s%s,

Tags: react-native

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
> built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
> but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
> default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at App.js:10.,
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> in RCTView (at NativeAppearance.tsx:4)
> in FallbackAppearanceProvider (at src/index.tsx:70)
> in AppearanceProvider (created by ExpoRoot)
> in RootErrorBoundary (created by ExpoRoot)
> in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
> in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:109)
> in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:135)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

export code is there. What is the problem in the code please?

**App.js code**

```js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { HotelComp } from "./components/hotel";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <HotelComp />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

**hotel.js code**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

export class hotel extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> hotel Component </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default hotel;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the class exported twice, and you are importing `hotelComp`, not `hotel`. Try this for hotel.js:

```
export default class hotel extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> hotel Component </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And import it like this (assuming the hotel.js file is in the /components folder):

```
import hotel from "./components/hotel"
```